# ArrayList<AbstractObject> adding objects which extended AbstractObject is not possible. How to fix it?

Tags: kotlin

So I have `ArrayList<AbstractObject>` which is class type `abstract`. And I have 2 items which **extends** `AbstractObject`. If I use `abstractList.add(Object1)` it says that **ArrayList expects object of type AbstractObject and not Object1**. I thought that this is possible. Reason why I want to do this is to use multiple objects with 2 different data in single `RecyclerView`. (`ViewTypes`)

```
abstract class ListItem {

    abstract val type: Int

    companion object {
        const val TYPE_HEADER = 0
        const val TYPE_ITEM = 1
    }

}

class HeaderItem(val headerTitle: String) : ListItem() {

    val type: Int
        get() = TYPE_HEADER

}

class ObjectItem(val object: ParseObject) : ListItem() {


    val type: Int
        get() = TYPE_ITEM

}
```

**Init #1:**

```
var recyclerViewArray: ArrayList<out ListItem> = ArrayList()
```

This is error if I want to add HeaderItem to this list:

[image]

**Init #2:**

```
var recyclerViewArray: ArrayList<ListItem> = ArrayList()
```

This says `Type mismatch`. Tried with `as` but `as` is yellowed with message `This cast can never succeed.`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and it works fine. If in some expression Kotlin infers the type wrong, you can always specify it manually. In your case

```
abstractList.add(Object1 as AbstractObject)
```

Comment: this doesnt work, "as" says This cast can never succeed. Ive tried to define ArrayList<out AbstractClass> but this has out-projected type exception.

Comment: Looks like `Object1` doesn't derive from `AbtractObject`. Can you add the code that shows your definitions of those two classes, and the code where you're trying to add the object to the list?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `out` from the declaration of `recyclerViewArray` and it should work (I just tried it and it ran fine). e.g. I could run this line of code:

```
recyclerViewArray.add(HeaderItem("test"))
```

Note that when you remove `out` you still need to keep the fact that it's an `ArrayList` of `ListItem` objects.  So you should declare it as:

```
var recyclerViewArray = arrayListOf<ListItem>()
```

Some of your code didn't quite compile for me, like having a property called `object` (I had to put backticks around that) and not putting the `override` modifier on the `type` property on `HeaderItem`.

Comment: I have fixed that. There should not be override, I need those types only for recyclerviewAdapter to know which layout it should inflate => it is ViewType for Adapter. And with your solution it doesn't work for me. Type mismatch error.

Comment: What version of Kotlin are you using?  And what tool are you using to compile the code?  I'm on Kotlin 1.3 with IntelliJ (and also tried with Gradle for the compilation) and in both cases if you have an abstract property you must put the `override` keyword where you implement it, otherwise you get this error: `type hides member of supertype ListItem and needs override modifier`.

Comment: Also, just a stab in the dark here: when you are declaring recyclerViewArray, are you definitely referring to the same `ListItem` class as in the declarations of `HeaderItem` and `ObjectItem`?  Do you accidentally have two `ListItem` classes kicking about somewhere, maybe from a 3rd party library?  Might be worth checking they're definitely in the same package in all cases.